# How to Juxtapose DIV and Anchor

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML:

```
<DIV class = "parent">
   <DIV class = "child">
   <Anchor ...>
</DIV>
```

How can I make sure that DIV and Anchor siblings are right-centered and next to each other?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: `Juxtapose` that was a heavy word, used a dictionary to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Set your `.child` div to `display: inline`.
2. Set a width for your parent div, and set its right and left margins
   to `auto`

CSS would look like:

```
div.child { display: inline; }
div.parent { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Adjust the parent width to your needs.

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/ca725) .

Comment: Thanks, Nelson. I'll try this out now. Can you please fix link? I got a 111 error when opening it.

Comment: The link is opening fine for me, is a https link, anyway I've made a copy on jsfiddle so you can try that also, here -> http://jsfiddle.net/w7Q53/